# Node.js app deployment on AWS using Otto

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, phusion-passenger, otto

When trying to use [Otto](https://ottoproject.io/) to deploy a Node.js application, the deployed application is not reachable.

I have created a [minimal application](https://github.com/jpsecher/nodeotto/tree/42dbe97105e3fc170fdaf06274adf1f766bad109) that simply listens on port 80 and answers status requests:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 80;
app.get('/status',function(req,res){
    res.json({
        hostname: req.hostname,
        address: req.ip
    });
});
var server = app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('PORT='+port);
});
```

The local virtual machine created by Otto works fine:

```
host$ otto compile
host$ otto dev
host$ otto dev ssh

guest$ npm install
guest$ sudo npm start

host$ curl http://`otto dev address`/status
```

However, when the application is deployed on AWS by

```
host$ otto infra
host$ otto build
host$ otto deploy
host$ otto deploy info
```

then the application cannot be reached through the nginx that Otto puts in front of it, which means that something like this request fails:

```
host$ curl http://ec2-...amazonaws.com/status
```

If I ssh into the deployed server

```
host$ ssh ubuntu@ec2-...amazonaws.com
```

then I cannot start the node app because port 80 is already taken:

```
ubuntu$ cd /srv/otto-app
ubuntu$ sudo npm start
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::80
```

but I can change the port to 8080 and start the node app:

```
ubuntu$ sudo vi server.js
ubuntu$ npm start
```

and then I can get through to the node app:

```
host$ curl http://ec2-...amazonaws.com:8080/status
```

I am completely new to [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/), [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) and [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/).

What is needed to instruct Otto to provision the AWS virtual machine or properly start up the Node app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otto deploys [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) together with nginx to manage the Node application, and in that constellation Passenger [defaults to expect](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#example-2) that a Node application has an `app.js` in the application root as the main file.

And Passenger remaps whatever port the Node application is running on, so the application should just be started on some available user port, not port 80.

The [minimal example code](https://github.com/jpsecher/nodeotto) has now been updated so that the deployed AWS server works.